# Unable to write Blood pressure in Google Fit in android Java. Below is my sample code that I am integrating to write Bloop Pressure

Tags: google-fit

```
fitnessOptions =FitnessOptions.builder().addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
.addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
.addDataType(HealthDataTypes.AGGREGATE_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
.addDataType(HealthDataTypes.AGGREGATE_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SUMMARY, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
.build(); 


private void insertBP() {
        // [START build_insert_data_request]


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() - 500;
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() - 100;
        // Create a data source
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                .setAppPackageName(this)
                .setStreamName("$TAG - Blood Pressure")
                .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE)

                .build();

        DataPoint dataPoint =
                DataPoint.builder(dataSource)
                        .setTimestamp(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
//                            .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_DIASTOLIC, 90.0f)
                        .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_SYSTOLIC, 125.0f)
                        .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_BODY_POSITION, HealthFields.BODY_POSITION_SITTING)
                        .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_LOCATION, HealthFields.BLOOD_PRESSURE_MEASUREMENT_LOCATION_LEFT_UPPER_ARM)
                        .build();
        DataSet dataSet = DataSet.builder(dataSource)
                .add(dataPoint)
                .build();


        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .insertData(dataSet)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Total BP Added: " + "Added---" + dataSet);
                        readBPData();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Total BP: " + "Not Added---" + dataSet);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You are logging that the point is not added, but you're ignoring the exception. Perhaps that has some relevant information?

Comment: I am getting Exception : com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5024:
I tried to find out its solution but unable to resolve this.